# Can I add a Processor to just one Monolog handler?

Tags: monolog, stackify

Can I add a Processor to just one Monolog handler? Or is there some other way I can alter a message that is only going out to one particular handler?

I want to add a text string to the end of `$record['message']`. I can do this now with a processor, but it affects all my handlers, which is no good for my situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this link can help you out:
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#customizing-the-log-format

Also you can add a processor directly to the handler:

```
$stackifyHandler->pushProcessor(<callable>);
```

[image: Adds a processor in the stack]

Comment: Adding a processor to just the handler was exactly what I needed. Thank you!